# Netty server does not sent "Certificate Request"

Tags: ssl, certificate, netty, wireshark, tls1.2

TLS handshake is completed but I can not see "certificate request" when I check with wireshark.

I am using netty as a server.

[image]

Please help me :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. Netty did not send a request because my truststore was empty. Thanks.